# Windows phone 8 Sqlite setup

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I started setting up the windows phone 8 sqlite and everything worked out great. I installed the SQL for Windows phone extension. Then i proceeded on adding the solution (Sqlite.vcxproj). After that i added the files Sqlite.cs and SqliteAsync.cs. Then i referenced the sqlite for windows phone in add reference and everything seemed fine. Finally I added the USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE to the build properties. (I followed -> [THIS guide](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20qmatteoq_eng%20%28qmatteoq.com%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader))

First i had problems with SQLite3 missing namespace but then I fixed it after manually adding Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.WP.dll, Community.CsharpSqlite.WinPhone.dll, System.Data.Ersatz.WinPhone.dll.

Problem is, when I insert this code:

```
private async void CreateDatabase()
{
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "people.db"), true);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<Person>();
}
```

i keep getting namespace name SQLiteAsyncConnection could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?) errors.

is this happening because i cannot add the sqlite3 dll manualy ?( i get the pesky "a reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project" error). the SQLite for windows phone is added to the reference tho.

Comment: Did you deviate from the [instructions on sqlite-net-wp8's page](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8)?  You don't need CSharpSqlite, as sqlite-net-wp8 is meant to be used in its stead as a wrapper around the native sqlite library.  SQLiteAsyncConnection should be found as SqliteAsync.cs should be in your project.  Note that its namespace is 'SQLite' and not 'SQLite3'.

Comment: I was hoping it would somehow work but to no avail, yes the SqliteAsync.cs is in my project but it still doesnt work, check the comment i made under the bottom answer for a picture of my solution explorer. Everything seems to be in place yet it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need a reference from your project to "SQLite for Windows Phone" as the Sqlite project already contains a reference to it.  You should be referencing Sqlite (the one from sqlite-net-wp8) as a project reference from your project.

Comment: Sqlite.vcxproj is already referenced to my project as you can see from the picture below<http://shrani.si/f/1M/Zp/cgC81OA/references.jpg>. Its referenced as a solution to my project.

Comment: but the problem persits, its like the sqliteasync.cs is not there but its added to my project just like sqlite.cs...

Comment: And you have a "using SQLite;" statement in the file containing the code above, correct?

Comment: oh my gosh. I cannot believe what mistake have i done. Damn. Thank you Peter Heune. Seriously, thank you for helping me. my problem is solved :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: if you get your question solved please give some point who helped you to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "people.db"), true);
```

Next open connection

```
await conn.OpenAsync();
string empPersionallInfo = "create table if not exists EmpInfo" + "(no int," + "name varchar(20))";
await conn.ExecuteStatementAsync(empPersionallInfo);
```